# Blazor DataAnnotationsValidation Tabbing question

Tags: c#, forms, blazor, .net-8.0

I am using Blazor to write a form for a client. Now not having worked with Blazor since pre-release I wanted to see the most effective way to validate forms using `<EditForm>`.

I have decided to look at the `DataAnnotationsValidator` for this as they made a few changes in .NET 8.

Ideally I want the form validation to prompt when tabbing over the `<InputText>` box and display the message below. However  `<ValidationMessage For="() => class.test"/>` is only displaying after I have triggered a range error or submitted.

Is there a way I can have these errors trigger when tabbing over the fields as well as when submitting?

This is an example project I just quickly made up to replicate the issue. My actual form is a lot deeper than this.

```cs
@using BlazorAppForTesting.Components.ComponantIH
@using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations

@page "/modaltest"
    <EditForm Model="_testClass" OnValidSubmit="OnValidSubmit" FormName="Example Form">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="make">Make:</label>
                <InputText id="make" class="form-control" @bind-Value="_testClass.make" />
                <ValidationMessage For="@(() => _testClass.make)" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="model">Model:</label>
                <InputText id="model" class="form-control" @bind-Value="_testClass.model" />
                <ValidationMessage For="@(() => _testClass.model)" />
            </div>
    <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>
</EditForm>

@code {
    public class TestClass123
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "This Field is required")]
        [MaxLength(10, ErrorMessage = "Max Length is 10")]
        public string make { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "This Field is required")]
        [MaxLength(20, ErrorMessage = "Max Length is 20")]
        public string model { get; set; }
    }

    public TestClass123 _testClass = new TestClass123();


    public void OnValidSubmit()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Form Submitted");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are referring to tabbing or exiting an input without entering a value not triggering a validation event.

This is because you haven't changed the value in the control.  There's no `FieldChanged` event raised by the input on the `EditContext`.  The validator is wired into this event and runs specific field validation when it is raised.

A quick and dirty solution is to manually wire up the `onblur` event to trigger the event.  This will trigger the event twice if you actually enter a value, but you can probably  live with that.  Doing it properly requires customized input controls.

Here's your code showing how you can do it:

```cs
@page "/counter"
@using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations

@page "/modaltest"
<EditForm EditContext="_editContext" OnValidSubmit="OnValidSubmit" FormName="Example Form">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="make">Make:</label>
        <InputText id="make" class="form-control" @bind-Value="_testClass.make" @onblur="@(() => this.OnBlurValidate("make"))" />
        <ValidationMessage For="@(() => _testClass.make)" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="model">Model:</label>
        <InputText id="model" class="form-control" @bind-Value="_testClass.model" @onblur="@(() => this.OnBlurValidate("model"))" />
        <ValidationMessage For="@(() => _testClass.model)" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>
</EditForm>

@code {
    private EditContext? _editContext;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        _editContext = new(_testClass);
        base.OnInitialized();
    }

    public class TestClass123
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "This Field is required")]
        [MaxLength(10, ErrorMessage = "Max Length is 10")]
        public string make { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "This Field is required")]
        [MaxLength(20, ErrorMessage = "Max Length is 20")]
        public string model { get; set; }

    }

    public TestClass123 _testClass = new TestClass123();

    public void OnBlurValidate(string fieldName)
    {
        // create a Field Identifier for the field
        FieldIdentifier fi = new(_testClass, fieldName);
        // Notify the edit context that the field has changed.  This will raise the necessary events to trigger specifc field validation
        _editContext?.NotifyFieldChanged(fi);
    }

    public void OnValidSubmit()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Form Submitted");
    }
}
```